# View not updating after change to array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I am trying to add a new item to an array. The item gets added correctly, but the display does not reflect the change.

**Add new task:**

```
 $scope.addNewTask = function() 
 {  
    console.log( "Before: " + $scope.tasks.length );

    $scope.newTask = [
        {
            id:     '3',
            title:  'Get answer'
        }
    ];

    $scope.tasks.push( $scope.newTask[0] );

    console.log( "After: " + $scope.tasks.length ); // one more than before
};
```

**Task array:**

```
$scope.tasks = [
    {
        id:     '1',
        title:  'Run into problem'
    },
    {
        id:     '2',
        title:  'Ask question'
    }
];
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks>
        {{ task.id }} {{ task.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

While I can see on the console that the new item was added, the list is not updating to reflect the change.

Edit: Don't know if it makes any difference, but the function is called upon clicking the submit button of a form as follows:

```
<form class="newtask-form" ng-submit="addNewTask()">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add new task" />
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe it too hard to do, but next time try to show how it works in Fiddle or Plunker, to detect the issue and fix quickly.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecJUJ/. I just copy and pasted your code and it works. Except by the missing **"** to close the ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately it turned out to be something else (see my own answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I solved it. The problem was this: In my code, I set ng-controller manually outside of ng-view. However, through the router, the controller for the view was set to the same controller.

So I believe what happened is that I had two nested controller objects, one with the tasks that got changed through the form submit, and another one with the tasks that got displayed through the li.

Ultimately, it looks like I will need to restructure my application and start using services for my data rather than stuffing it all into my controller (any good introductions about services are appreciated). But at least now I have an idea what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an `ng-click` on the `input` itself rather than `ng-submit` on the form.

```
    <form class="newtask-form">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" 
               ng-click="addNewTask()" value="Add new task" />
    </form>
```

Not sure if that should make a difference but it's the only thing I could think of (other than calling `scope.$apply()` which you've already did.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately it turned out to be something else (see my own answer).